# Why do we need boost::thread_specific_ptr?

Tags: boost, boost-thread

Why do we need boost::thread_specific_ptr, or in other words what can we not easily do without it?

I can see why pthread provides pthread_getspecific() etc. These functions are useful for cleaning up after dead threads, and handy to call from C-style functions (the obvious alternative being to pass a pointer everywhere that points to some memory allocated before the thread was created).

In contrast, the constructor of boost:thread takes a callable class by value, and everything non-static in that class becomes thread local once it is copied. I cannot see why I would want to use boost::thread_specific_ptr in preference to a class member any more than I would want to use a global variable in OOP code.

Do I horribly misunderstand anything? A very brief example would help, please. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread_specific_ptr` simply provides **portable** thread local data access.  You don't have to be managing your threads with Boost.Thread to get value from this.  The canonical example is the one cited in the Boost docs for this class:

> One example is the C errno variable,
>   used for storing the error code
>   related to functions from the Standard
>   C library. It is common practice (and
>   required by POSIX) for compilers that
>   support multi-threaded applications to
>   provide a separate instance of errno
>   for each thread, in order to avoid
>   different threads competing to read or
>   update the value.

Comment: just to add my 2 cents: it's also known under the term `Thread Local Storage` and is useful in many elegant multithreading optimizations

Comment: @Andy - right. I've seen a case where numerical analysis code uses a thread-local random-number generator for example.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: very good point, and many thanks for your answer. So to rephrase, is there any reason why I would want to use boost::thread and boost::thread_specific_ptr at the same time?

Comment: @Andy: I don't understand. As far as I can see, TLS helps you avoid passing an extra pointer around, and to clean up afterwards. Did you have something closely related to this in mind, or do you mean optimisation for speed? If the latter, could you please briefly explain where the speedup comes from?

Comment: Imagine you have parallelizable code using OpenMP.  That code could use a variable of type `thread_specific_ptr` to handle its context, without needing the overhead of boost::thread for thread management.

Comment: @Joe: yeah, I mean speed optimization, TSL helps to avoid expensive locking. The first example that came to my mind is global memory pool with local preallocated chunks for each thread. So every thread can allocate from its own chunk w/o frequent locking of global pool. Such chunks are kept in TSL.

Comment: @Andy: many thanks. I can see how having an allocation pool for every thread is a good thing. I cannot see how that provides any more speed than just allocating a pool for every thread when it's created. To put this another way, why is there support for TLS in the the Linux kernel when the same effect can be achieved in userspace?

Comment: The main advantage of TLS is that it allows you to store per-thread data from code that is not in charge of the thread lifetime.  If you can allocate memory at thread-creation time, then by all means do that -- it's better.  But sometimes (due to code structure, eg. being a library) this is not possible, and this is where TLS comes into play.